# Ajax call firing multiple times each time i open the modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, ajaxform

I am creating a crud through ajax and this is an edit function, if i open modal and make some change and submit it works fine the first time, if i submit the form a second time it edits both records the current and the last one too, meaning firing twice, it fires thrice in 3rd turn editing 3 records at once when it should only edit one.

```
function EditCategory(id) {

    $('#edit-modal').modal('show');
    $('#edit_message').html('');
    $("#edit_message").attr('class', 'alert');
    $('#edit_message').css('display', 'none');
    $('#notification').html('');
    $('#notification').attr('class', 'alert');
    $('#notification').css('display', 'none');

    var category_name = document.getElementById('categoryCode' + id).getElementsByTagName('h4');
    var category_color = document.getElementById('categoryCode' + id).getElementsByTagName('input');
    $('#edit_category_name').val(category_name[0].innerHTML);
    $('#edit_background_color').val(category_color[0].value);

    $('#form-edit').on('submit', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        $('#edit_message').html('');
        $("#edit_message").attr('class', 'alert');
        $('#edit_message').css('display', 'none');

        var name = document.getElementById('edit_category_name').value;
        var color = document.getElementById('edit_background_color').value;

        console.log(name);
        console.log(color);
        console.log(id);


        var file_data = $('#edit_img').prop('files')[0];

        var form_data = new FormData();

        form_data.append('category_name', name);
        form_data.append('img', file_data);
        form_data.append('background_color', color);
        form_data.append('id', id);

        $.ajax({

            url: "{{ url('categories/update') }}",
            method: "POST",
            data: form_data,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(data) {

                $('#edit_message').css('display', 'block');
                $('#edit_message').addClass(data.class_name);

                if (data.class_name == 'alert-danger') {
                    $('#edit_message').html("Error! " + data.message);
                } else {
                    $('#edit_message').html(data.message);
                }

                if (data.class_name == 'alert-success') {
                    document.getElementById('categoryCode' + data.id).getElementsByTagName('h4')
                        .innerHTML = data.name;
                    document.getElementById('categoryCode' + data.id).getElementsByTagName('input')
                        .value = data.color;
                    document.getElementById('categoryCode' + data.id).getElementsByTagName('img')
                        .src = data.src;
                }

            }

            //ajax end
        });

        //edit form end
    });

    //edit end

}
```

Comment: You’re binding a new listener to the submit event whenever you open the modal.

Comment: Each time this function is called, it adds a new `.on('submit')`. Trigger this function 3 times, you will get 3 `.on('submit')`, thus 3 ajax calls.

Comment: thank you jeremy, how can resolve this, i need to send some values like id in the submit function thats why i put it inside the onclick function

Comment: @terry how can resolve this, i need to send some values like id in the submit function thats why i put it inside the onclick function

Comment: @sheharyaranwer you can add an event on your form that call EditCategory when the page is loaded.

Comment: A quick stop-gap solution will be to do `$('#form-edit').off('submit')` either when the modal is opened, or when the AJAX call returns a response. However, this depends on what your user story is, since in your code there is no logic that closes the modal.